# Sending URL with Nodejs and Get Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, get

Hey guys can someone help me with that issue

im new on node.js and im studing and starting a project.

what i need to do is:

i need to send an url to a webservice and get the response from the webservice, for example:

i send http://www.webservice.com.br/getserver?user=myuser&password=mypassword

after that the webservice will give me a response at his page a succes/error message or a new url for login example http://history.webservice.com.br

so i need to get the response after sending an url someone know how can i do that with node.js ?

in php would be something like that
/*
 * $sendurl = "myUrlHere";
 * $getserver = file($sendurl);
 * var_dump($getserver);
 */

in this php example i send the url and i get the response withou leaving my page.

if someone know how i do that in node or give me a way i will appreciate.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Congrats on your first SO question!  In general, it's nice to post the code you've tried so far, rather than asking others to write all the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, sending username passwords directly in url get requests is a disaster! By the way, I think you are just playing around with node, so this is forgivable ;) Following is a sample code for you to do http requests to your web service:

```
var http = require('http');
http.get("http://www.webservice.com.br/getserver?user=myuser&password=mypassword", function(res) {
    //this is http response status code
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    //this is headers
    console.log(res.headers);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        //this is body
        console.log(chunk);
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```